# Open Gapps Google Services installation on Android 5.0 based TV

Tags: youtube, gapps

Device: 
manta.com.pl 43" TV with Android 5.0 on the board. 
I have an root access through ADB shell.

Issue: 
I need google services to run Youtube for Android TV.

How I tried to solve:
I [donwloaded](https://opengapps.org/) Open Gapps Nano for Android 5.0, extracted a few files from it and pushed to the /system partition. I don't have TWRP recovery there.

```
.
./etc
./etc/preferred-apps
./etc/preferred-apps/google.xml
./etc/permissions
./etc/permissions/com.google.widevine.software.drm.xml
./etc/permissions/com.google.android.media.effects.xml
./etc/permissions/com.google.android.maps.xml
./etc/sysconfig
./etc/sysconfig/google_build.xml
./etc/sysconfig/google.xml
./priv-app
./priv-app/PrebuiltGmsCore
./priv-app/PrebuiltGmsCore/PrebuiltGmsCore.apk
./priv-app/PrebuiltGmsCore/lib
./priv-app/PrebuiltGmsCore/lib/arm
./priv-app/PrebuiltGmsCore/lib/arm/libconscrypt_gmscore_jni.so
./priv-app/PrebuiltGmsCore/lib/arm/libwearable-selector.so
./priv-app/PrebuiltGmsCore/lib/arm/libAppDataSearch.so
./priv-app/PrebuiltGmsCore/lib/arm/libleveldbjni.so
./priv-app/PrebuiltGmsCore/lib/arm/libgcastv2_support.so
./priv-app/PrebuiltGmsCore/lib/arm/libgoogle-ocrclient-v3.so
./priv-app/PrebuiltGmsCore/lib/arm/libinertial-anchor-jni.so
./priv-app/PrebuiltGmsCore/lib/arm/libWhisper.so
./priv-app/PrebuiltGmsCore/lib/arm/libgcastv2_base.so
./priv-app/PrebuiltGmsCore/lib/arm/libjingle_peerconnection_so.so
./priv-app/PrebuiltGmsCore/lib/arm/libjgcastservice.so
./priv-app/PrebuiltGmsCore/lib/arm/libgmscore.so
./priv-app/PrebuiltGmsCore/lib/arm/libvcdiffjni.so
./priv-app/PrebuiltGmsCore/lib/arm/libsslwrapper_jni.so
./priv-app/GoogleServicesFramework
./priv-app/GoogleServicesFramework/GoogleServicesFramework.apk
./priv-app/GoogleBackupTransport
./priv-app/GoogleBackupTransport/GoogleBackupTransport.apk
./framework
./framework/com.google.android.maps.jar
./framework/com.google.android.media.effects.jar
./framework/com.google.widevine.software.drm.jar
```

But google services don't start, I see the following native crash:

```
    I/ActivityManager( 2608): Start proc com.google.android.gms for service com.google.android.gms/.chimera.GmsIntentOperationService: pid=3452 uid=10014 gids={50014, 9997, 3003, 1028, 1015, 3002, 3001, 1005, 1007, 3007, 2001, 3006} abi=armeabi-v7a
W/ProviderHelper( 3430): Unknown dynamite feature providerinstaller
I/DynamiteModule( 3430): Considering local module providerinstaller:0 and remote module providerinstaller:0
W/ProviderInstaller( 3430): Failed to load providerinstaller module: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
V/NativeCrypto( 3430): Registering com/google/android/gms/org/conscrypt/NativeCrypto's 286 native methods...
W/ResourcesManager( 3452): Asset path '/system/framework/com.android.media.remotedisplay.jar' does not exist or contains no resources.
W/ResourcesManager( 3452): Asset path '/system/framework/com.android.location.provider.jar' does not exist or contains no resources.
W/ActivityThread( 3430): ClassLoader.loadClass: The class loader returned by Thread.getContextClassLoader() may fail for processes that host multiple applications. You should explicitly specify a context class loader. For example: Thread.setContextClassLoader(getClass().getClassLoader());
W/System  ( 3430): Could not create com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketFactoryImpl with ClassLoader android.app.LoadedApk$WarningContextClassLoader@3dc96d1d: com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketFactoryImpl
I/ProviderInstaller( 3430): Installed default security provider GmsCore_OpenSSL
I/art     ( 3172): Explicit concurrent mark sweep GC freed 2659(106KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 39% free, 4MB/7MB, paused 1.726ms total 35.015ms
I/Safeboot( 3430): Checking safeboot...
W/art     ( 3452): Verification of void rtf.onCreate() took 138.949ms
W/DynamiteModule( 3452): Local module descriptor class for providerinstaller not found.
W/ProviderHelper( 3452): Unknown dynamite feature providerinstaller
I/DynamiteModule( 3452): Considering local module providerinstaller:0 and remote module providerinstaller:0
W/ProviderInstaller( 3452): Failed to load providerinstaller module: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
V/NativeCrypto( 3452): Registering com/google/android/gms/org/conscrypt/NativeCrypto's 286 native methods...
I/art     ( 3430): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 33203(1508KB) AllocSpace objects, 1(16KB) LOS objects, 13% free, 10MB/11MB, paused 7.459ms total 861.420ms
I/Safeboot Condition( 3430): No need to enter Safeboot.
W/Primes  ( 3430): Primes not initialized, returning default (no-op) Primes instance which will ignore all calls. Please call Primes.initialize(...) before using any Primes API.
W/ActivityThread( 3452): ClassLoader.loadClass: The class loader returned by Thread.getContextClassLoader() may fail for processes that host multiple applications. You should explicitly specify a context class loader. For example: Thread.setContextClassLoader(getClass().getClassLoader());
W/System  ( 3452): Could not create com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketFactoryImpl with ClassLoader android.app.LoadedApk$WarningContextClassLoader@21fd60b7: com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketFactoryImpl
I/ProviderInstaller( 3452): Installed default security provider GmsCore_OpenSSL
I/Safeboot( 3452): Checking safeboot...
I/Safeboot( 3452): Not entering safeboot; wrong process.
W/art     ( 3452): Suspending all threads took: 6.199ms
W/Primes  ( 3452): Primes not initialized, returning default (no-op) Primes instance which will ignore all calls. Please call Primes.initialize(...) before using any Primes API.
I/art     ( 3452): WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 3.045s for cause HomogeneousSpaceCompact
W/art     ( 3452): Suspending all threads took: 9.346ms
F/libc    ( 3452): Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 3452 (gle.android.gms)
I/DEBUG   ( 3304): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
I/DEBUG   ( 3304): Build fingerprint: 'AndroidTV/nt72668_hikeen/nt72668_hikeen:5.0/LRX22C/huangds04090501:userdebug/release-keys'
I/DEBUG   ( 3304): Revision: '0'
I/DEBUG   ( 3304): ABI: 'arm'
I/DEBUG   ( 3304): pid: 3452, tid: 3452, name: gle.android.gms  >>> com.google.android.gms <<<
I/DEBUG   ( 3304): signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
I/DEBUG   ( 3304):     r0 00000000  r1 00000d7c  r2 00000006  r3 00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 3304):     r4 b6736114  r5 00000006  r6 0000000b  r7 0000010c
I/DEBUG   ( 3304):     r8 2b4ae920  r9 a3aa2761  sl 00000000  fp be41a8b8
I/DEBUG   ( 3304):     ip 00000d7c  sp be41a578  lr b66bff29  pc b66e4250  cpsr 600e0010
I/DEBUG   ( 3304): 
I/DEBUG   ( 3304): backtrace:
I/DEBUG   ( 3304):     #00 pc 0003b250  /system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+12)
I/DEBUG   ( 3304):     #01 pc 00016f25  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_kill+52)
I/DEBUG   ( 3304):     #02 pc 00017b43  /system/lib/libc.so (raise+10)
I/DEBUG   ( 3304):     #03 pc 00014399  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_android_abort+36)
I/DEBUG   ( 3304):     #04 pc 00012b68  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+4)
I/DEBUG   ( 3304):     #05 pc 000a082d  /system/priv-app/PrebuiltGmsCore/lib/arm/libconscrypt_gmscore_jni.so
I/DEBUG   ( 3304):     #06 pc 00017557  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_once+90)
I/DEBUG   ( 3304):     #07 pc 00072fc5  /system/priv-app/PrebuiltGmsCore/lib/arm/libconscrypt_gmscore_jni.so
I/DEBUG   ( 3304):     #08 pc 000a086d  /system/priv-app/PrebuiltGmsCore/lib/arm/libconscrypt_gmscore_jni.so
I/DEBUG   ( 3304):     #09 pc 000a063f  /system/priv-app/PrebuiltGmsCore/lib/arm/libconscrypt_gmscore_jni.so
I/DEBUG   ( 3304):     #10 pc 000a0753  /system/priv-app/PrebuiltGmsCore/lib/arm/libconscrypt_gmscore_jni.so
I/DEBUG   ( 3304):     #11 pc 0003c70b  /system/priv-app/PrebuiltGmsCore/lib/arm/libconscrypt_gmscore_jni.so
I/DEBUG   ( 3304):     #12 pc 01c9a8bd  /data/dalvik-cache/arm/system@priv-app@PrebuiltGmsCore@PrebuiltGmsCore.apk@classes.dex
I/DEBUG   ( 3304): 
I/DEBUG   ( 3304): Tombstone written to: /data/tombstones/tombstone_00
W/art     ( 3430): Suspending all threads took: 1.387s
```

Any suggestions how I can solve it?

Comment: I think you need Google Account Manager first, then the Google Services Framework to install Google Play Services?

Comment: Do I need Google Account Manager and Google Play?

Comment: Yes. You need them since Youtube is a google app. You need Google Account Manager, Google Services Framework and then Google Play Services. As for Google Play, if you can install it it is the easiest way to install Youtube afterwards.